# Parse nbd.Key(urlsafe=string) externally

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform

I am a bit further. I am getting the key representatation in Google Apps Script of a key created with nbd.Key() in python.

When I decode this key, I get an incomplete set of data:

```
agxzfm92ZXItc2lnaHRyJwsSCEN1c3RvbWVyIghzeXNhZG1pbgwLEglDb25kaXRpb24YpJwBDA
```

When I convert that back, I get readable entities, but I miss the ID. This is base64decoded:

```
"js~over-sightr'Customer"sysadmin   Condition��"
```

Is there a way to get everything back without needing Python?

Old post:

> In Google Datastore, a set of scores is saved to the DataStore as
>   nbd.jsonProperty.
>
> I can parse this in Google Apps Script, and I get a set of data. Now I
>   find for each element the following structure:
>
> ```
> [
>  {"not_applicable":false,
>   "key":"aghxxxxxxxxxxIUXVlc3Rpb24YgICAgPjChAoM",
>   "given_score":0
>  },
>  ...
> ]
> ```
>
> The key here, I can base64decode. I see that I find the related
>   question information (the key points to another entity).  It shows a
>
> char+datastoreId+char+kind+?I expect the key here?
>
> Exept, how can I get that last part? The base64 decoder gives stange
>   characters for that last part, but I suspect there is the ID as a
>   number in there.
>
> I am using Google Apps Script. Can I get this ID from this encoded
>   string? I cannot post the whole string, but the last part of the byte
>   array is [-128, -128, -128, -8, -62, -124, 10, 12] and I suspect this
>   represents the ID.
>
> Any ideas or experience?

Comment: Actually, I found out what it should become:
PjChAoM should be translated to 5649391675244544

But how?

Answer (score 1):

The URLSafe keys (specific to the Python client library) is a Base64 encoded version of an internal protobuf v1 representation of the Entity Key. It was not designed to be decoded externally.

I don't think Apps Script has an easy way to consume protobuf messages, however you could theoretically implement it by looking at the NDB implementation combined with an understanding of how Protocol Buffers encodes data.